# Fix my macvim installation to use most current version

Tags: vim, homebrew

I have 4 versions of macvim installed in homebrew's `Cellar` folder.  I want the most recent version only to be my default vim everywhere, ie, when I type `gvim` or `vim` from the command line.

`brew linkapps macvim` does not work, ie, `gvim` still gives "No such file" after running it.

Here's the current info:

```
$ brew info macvim
macvim: stable 7.4-85, HEAD
GUI for vim, made for OS X
https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72 (1799 files, 28M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73 (1810 files, 28M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1 (1810 files, 28M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-85 (1910 files, 35M)
  Built from source with: --with-lua --with-luajit --with-python3 --with-override-system-vim
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb
==> Dependencies
Recommended: cscope ✔
Optional: lua ✔, luajit ✔
==> Options
--with-custom-icons
    Try to generate custom document icons
--with-lua
    Build with lua support
--with-luajit
    Build with luajit support
--with-override-system-vim
    Override system vim
--with-python3
    Build with python3 support
--without-cscope
    Build without cscope support
--without-python
    Build without python support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps macvim` to symlink these to /Applications.
```

### UPDATE

When I run `brew doctor`, the relevant message is:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    macvim
    vim
```

However, when I `brew link macvim`, it links back up the previous version of macvim, rather than the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

Please run `brew prune` to remove broken links. Also `brew doctor` can help you finding additional problems.

Comment: I updated the OP with more info after trying both of these.  But it's not working yet... Should I just manually delete the old versions in the cellar with `rm -rf` or might that cause issues?

Comment: I figured it out... uninstalling and reinstalling worked.